# How to fast create a variable that all combined the string values ​of a particular column in a dataframe?

Tags: r, string, bigdata, paste, accumulator

temp_day is dataframe, and it has billion rows.

```
Height_classify <- data.frame(color = c('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'),
                                  min = c(0, 100,300,500,1000,2000,5000),
                                  max = c(100,300,500,1000,2000,5000,8000))

make_code <- function(temp_day, h_class){
  temp_class <- Height_classify %>% filter(color == h_class)
  min_godo <- temp_class[1,2]
  max_godo <- temp_class[1,3]
  temp_day_hight <- temp_day %>% filter(AltitudeActual_m >= min_godo & AltitudeActual_m < max_godo)
  polys <- stri_c("polys_", temp_class[1,1], " = [")
  hight_flight <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(temp_day_hight$mdH_CallSign)), stringsAsFactors = F)

  for (sFlight in hight_flight$Var1){

    temp_day_hight_flight <- temp_day_hight %>% filter(mdH_CallSign == sFlight)

    if (nrow(temp_day_hight_flight) >1){

      polys <- stri_c(polys, "[")

      for (i in 1:nrow(temp_day_hight_flight)){

        polys <- stri_c(polys, temp_day_hight_flight$coord[i]) 
        if (i < nrow(temp_day_hight_flight)){
          polys <- stri_c(polys, ", ")
        } else {
          polys <- stri_c(polys, "], ")
        }

      } # for i
    } # if
  }# for sFlight
  polys <- substr(polys, 1, nchar(polys)-2)
  polys <- stri_c(polys, "]\n\n")

  return(polys)
}
```

Combining many strings in a column takes a lot of time to produce the result.
I think it slows down as the values continue to accumulate in the variable.

```
polys <- stri_c(polys, temp_day_hight_flight$coord[i])
```

How can you switch to a function that works faster?

Comment: My English is not good. Please understand if the sentence is wrong.

Comment: Difficult to offer a solution without the original data frame but doing something like those nested for-loops you have will be very inefficient for operations on large data frames (>100k rows), let alone a billion. I would recommend looking at the `data.table` pkg if your dataset is <2 billion rows, or look in to uploading the data to a SQL server and using an odbc related package to work on it from there.